# Change native C command names and compiler messages

Tags: c, compilation

How can I be able to write C code with different command names instead of the existing, and also to get different compiling warning, errors etc?

For example, replace the 'while' loop declaration with 'foobar', so that:

```
foobar (i<10) i++;
```

will act as:

```
while (i<10) i++;
```

and to replace a compilation error message from:

```
prog.c:4:2: error: 'i' undeclared
```

to:

```
prog.c:4:2: banana kiwi: 'i' orange apple tomato
```

A use case for this is making C based on a human-language other than english.

Comment: No, there aren't any ways built into the language (apart from #define). You might be able to take an existing compiler (GCC or clang), modify *its* source code to change the keywords and messages, and use that version of the compiler.

Comment: Not looking for a built in solution. Could you detail about the existing compiler modification? I thinkg this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

For the input language, you can use macros to define alternate names for things.

```
#define foobar int
```

Or better to use `typedef` for types.

```
typedef int foobar;
```

Neither of these removes `int` from the namespace.

If the compiler is made using a grammar file and a compiler-compiler, then you may be able to edit the keywords in the grammar to change the names without introducing new names. This will be the .yacc or .bison or .antlr or sthg file.

For the error messages, those are going to be baked-in to the compiler or in a strings or config file. You'll have to edit those files, or better copy into new locale-variant and modify.

Or run the compiler with a filter that replaces `error` with `banana kiwi`. sed, awk, m4 -- many common tools for substitutions.

Comment: That should be `typedef int foobar;`

Comment: For the first part - looking for something which is not built in to C. The filters could be a nice hack for the errors issue

Answer (score 0):

To give an alias to a type you can use `typedef`:

```
typedef int foobar;
foobar i; // is a int
```

About the error message, it's more complicated and is inside the compiler code...

Comment: I changed the example above to show I am looking for a wider solution than typedefs. Preferably not an in-code solution, but something invisible to the programmer